# What is wrong with this method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, http-get

I am executing this function, and I do not know what I am missing but var BYE is empty when HELLO is full of HTML, how could this happen?.

```
$.get(path+'productor/masnotas.jsp', function(data){
                    var hello = data; 
                    var bye = $(data).find("#columna1");
                            $("#columnauno").append($(data).find("#columna1"));
                                    },'html');
```

Could Someone help me?

Edit: Sorry I am rushing, here is part of the content of data, then it goes with more HTML and is compossed by another div called #columna2, outside #columna1. And I want to, using one HTML/JSP, select and put each content in each column of the web when I update the page:

```
<html>
<!-- Primera Columna --> 
<div class="span-12 first" id="columna1">
<br>
   <div class="caja">
    <b>Cambios en las denuncias por Self</b>
    <p style="text-align: justify;">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       <a href="${self.monitor.basePath}siniestro/ayudaDenuncia.jsp" target="_blank">Leer más</a>
     </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="caja">
    <img border="0" align="left" src="${self.monitor.basePath}images/aapas.jpg"/>
    <b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</b>
    <p style="text-align: justify;"> 
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis condimentum purus vel diam dictum non pharetra dolor vulputate. Aenean sed sapien leo, sed laoreet risus. Duis dictum volutpat imperdiet. Donec eros nibh, accumsan condimentum euismod laoreet, auctor vel lacus. Pellentesque felis tortor, laoreet eget varius eget, iaculis vitae turpis. Cras lobortis malesuada erat, nec sodales tellus porttitor eu. Vestibulum porttitor, neque vel aliquet porttitor, est tortor commodo magna, id faucibus orci massa at velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse arcu quam, volutpat ut ullamcorper in, laoreet eget diam. Pellentesque in massa nec massa dapibus vehicula. Sed nec lectus nisi, sed pharetra est. Ut leo metus, sagittis non blandit ac, adipiscing eu leo. <a href="#" target="_blank">ver nota completa</a>
     </p>
    </div>
    <br>
```

**path is system path, the basepath = ${self.monitor.basePath}**
**VARS created are made for testing purposes**

Comment: @AndreaTurri I rather suspect that for all of the faults in the question, knowing the `path` is not one of them.

Comment: Hm, so you assign `$(data).find("#columna1")` to a variable, only to execute it again on the next line?

Comment: Sime, i'm guessing the bye is for testing.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder Even then, a variable is not needed. You can inspect the value without having to put it in a variable.

Comment: I know, that is why I put it directly, check my coments below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately find won't work in this case because i'm suspecting `#columna1` is not a descendant. Try the following instead.

```
var bye = $('<div/>').html( data ).find('#columna1');
```

Comment: That first one needs some explaining, to me it looks like your trying to find `data` inside `#columna1` element ?

Comment: I have tried the first before posting here, let me try the second way you are talking about, thank you

Comment: I might have it backwards in the first one, i can never pull up the documentation for that one in time to look it up.

Comment: +1 .. yes, the first one should be reversed :) still doesn't work without wrapping it though.

Comment: The first one is now equal to the OP's version, as it's just a shortcut for `find()`.

Comment: If the element is in the root of the data variable, it probably will!

Comment: adeneo, it doesn't have to be at the root. Find will fetch anything that's a descendant.

Comment: This works. But instead of creating two vars, I just put it directly:
`$.get(path+'productor/masnotas.jsp', function(data){
     //var sec = $('<div/>').html( data ).find('#columna2'); 
     //var pri = $('<div/>').html( data ).find('#columna1');
           $("#columnauno").append($('<div/>').html( data ).find('#columna2'));
           $("#columnados").append($('<div/>').html( data ).find('#columna1'));
           },'html'); `

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but if it was'nt in the root, but where a descendant of another element, the OP's method of running find directly on the data variable should have found it. Anyway, looks like your answer worked, as it's accepted.

Comment: However, this was weird. I have done a research inmediately after my code goes bananas, and everybody uses: $('#columna1', data), when in my case, it was not working and I never discovered why.

Comment: Good point adeneo! You know i didn't fully understand this behavior but now that you pointed it out, it's clear why this works. Leandro because the element they were searching for was not the root element it was a descendant.

Comment: what do you mean by root? Sorry

Comment: The top most element e.g `<div id="root"> <div id="child"></div> </div>`

Comment: But in this HTML I just had #columna1 and #columna2, ¿childs of html tag?

Comment: Exactly in this `#columna1` was not a descendant, it was one of the root level elements. `.find` only works for descendants.

Comment: aaaaahhh, thank you, I did not know that feature of find(), thank you very much!